# Repository does not save entities after first save

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In spring boot integration test with full context loaded + h2. I have a problem. Only first .save invocation persist object to h2 but not any other (I see in logs only first save of entity). To be honest it looks like @Test is a transaction but I have not marked is as such.

Book also uses @Version. Yep I need to use optimistic locks. saveAndFlush does actually show me updated versions but doesn't throw OptimisticLockException even though it should because book column version in db shouldn't match book.version object.

```
   @Test
    void test(){
    Book book=new Book();
    book.setName("SuperBoook");
    bookRepository.save(book);
    book.setName("SuperBoookv1");
    bookRepository.save(book);
    book.setName("SuperBoookv2");
    bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

Comment: What about replacing `bookRepository.save(book);` with `book = bookRepository.save(book);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test class was annotated by @Transactional which cased test to not persist updated entity because test did not finish.